# random select consecutively week from different start week for different ID in R

Tags: r

the dataset is like:

```
ID week
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   6
1   7
2  10
2  11
2  12
2  13
2  14
3  13
3  14
3  15
3  16
3  17
3  18
3  19
3  20
3  21
3  22
```

each ID has different start week. I want to randomly select only for 3 consecutive weeks for each ID in R. the output will be like

```
ID   week
1      4
1      5
1      6
2     14
2     15
2     16
3     20
3     21
3     22
```

is there any faster to achieve it ? thanks

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[df1[, {i1 <- .I[sample(.N-2, 1)]; i1:(i1+2) } , ID]$V1]`

Comment: I tried 3-4 times.  Not able to get any error based on the example you showed

Comment: In that case `setDT(df1)[df1[, if(.N < 4) .I[1:.N] else {i1 <- .I[sample(.N-2, 1)]; i1:(i1+2) } , ID]$V1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, if(.N < 4) .I[1:.N] else {
             i1 <- .I[sample(.N-2, 1)]
             i1:(i1+2) } , by = ID]$V1]
```

Comment: curious why must put $V1 ? I tried to put $V . it also works . but other than V1 and V , all returns Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols). thanks

Comment: @Digi-fashion When we don't specify a column name, the default column created is V1 i.e. `i1:(i1+2)`.  THe reason that $V works is based on the partial matching.  Based on the example, I get the expected output